# How to make an oval radial gradient in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I need to do some radial gradients with non circular shapes in Flutter but I can't seem to find how to tweak the shape.

For example, this css:

```
background: radial-gradient(45.14% 37.78% at 50% 50%, #FFF 0%, rgba(40, 35, 35, 0.00) 100%);
```

[image: css-example]